# Python check if internet connection is via WiFi or Ethernet

Tags: python, serial-port, wifi, ethernet

I have been trying to make a program that checks if the machine is using Ethernet or WiFi connection(I can handle checking if it's connected to the internet).

So far I have not managed to achieve anything.
I have tried looking into the Serial/PySerial and Socket libraries yet hadn't found anything really...

I would really appreciate it if you have a lead or a code sample that I can try.

Comment: if you run Linux then in console you can run `ifconfig` and in output you should see all devices - ie. `wlp5s0:` means `WiFi` (`wl` means `wireless`), and `enp3s0:` means `Ethernet`. If device has assigned `inet` then it can means it is connected. So you could run it in Python using `subprocess.run("ifconfig", shell=True)`. But this needs more code to parse output from `ifconfig`.

Comment: you should also check module [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is wrapper on many system commands - and it uses also `ifconfig` - ie. `psutil.net_if_stats()` and `psutil.net_if_addrs()` give dictionary with keys like `enp3s0`, `wlp5s0`

Comment: something for Windows [Determine if a computer is connected to internet via WiFi network or ethernet cable in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766191/determine-if-a-computer-is-connected-to-internet-via-wifi-network-or-ethernet-ca) but this is 7 years old.